# How will God punish a person who deserts his wife?

Tags: sin

If a husband intentionally deserts his wife by listening to wrong and misleading people, then how will GOD punish him?

Answer (score 5):

God does not have to personally execute punishments. For that very purpose in the netherworld he has appointed Yama. And on the earth he appointed the Kings. God punishes through the Kings here as Kings represent the Gods on earth.

> Manu Smriti 9.303. Let the king emulate the energetic action of Indra,
>   of the Sun, of the Wind, of Yama, of Varuna, of the Moon, of the Fire,
>   and of the Earth
>
> Manu Smriti 9.308. As (a sinner) is seen bound with ropes by Varuna,
>   even so let him punish the wicked; that is his office in which he
>   resembles Varuna.

Unless the wife is guilty of a minor sin the wife must not be abandoned. A minor sin is called an Upapataka (which causes loss of caste) as opposed to a major sin which is called a Mahapataka.

The King can  punish such guilty husbands by imposing fines on them.

> Manu Smriti 8.389. Neither a mother, nor a father, **nor a wife**, nor a
>   son shall be cast off; **he who casts them off, unless guilty of a crime
>   causing loss of caste, shall be fined six hundred (panas)**

And casting off any relatives without sufficient reasons is also mentioned by Manu as an Upapataka.

> Manu Smriti 11.62. Living as a Vratya, **casting off a relative**,
>   teaching (the Veda) for wages, learning (the Veda) from a paid
>   teacher, and selling goods which one ought not to sell, are all minor
>   offences.

As per Vishnu Smriti, abandoning one's wife falls under "fourth degree  crimes".

> 6. (Abandoning) one's holy fire, or one's father, mother, son, or wife;
> 7. Thus have the crimes in the fourth degree been enumerated.
>
> **Vishnu Smriti, Chapter XXXVII.**

And,  another chapter of the same Smriti says that offenders guilty of such fourth degree crimes are re-born as aquatic animals in the next births.

> 4. Minor offenders enter the bodies of birds.
> 5. **Criminals in the fourth degree enter the bodies of aquatic animals**.
>
> **Vishnu Smriti, Chapter XLIV.**

And, as per the Daksha Smriti, the husband guilty of such crimes gets reborn as barren woman in the next birth.

> He, who renounces, in youth, a wife who is free from any fault and is
>   not degraded, **will attain, after death, to womanhood and become
>   barren.**
>
> **Daksha Smriti, Chapter 4, Verse 17.**

But, there are also prescribed penances or prayaschittas by performing which one gets relieved of one's sin in the current birth only.

Answer (score 1):

Before you get answer to this it is important to understand whether GOD punishes somebody for a wrong act done or is it something else.

I will explain it to you clearly. Everything in this world works on a Law. For good actions you perform, you get good returns. For bad actions, you get bad returns. If you help somebody, you will get blessing in return from that person and that will be added to your fortune and will be responsible for your Good Luck in life. Similarly, if you hurt somebody, you will create a Bad Luck for you yourself. This can also be called as the universal LAW OF KARMA. God has nothing to do about it. He won't punish anybody being the most loving, most caring and most obedient father of the Humanity. All the scriptures which we read has his teachings about what kind of actions one perform, what are good actions, what are bad actions and why one should not perform any sins. The reason is everything in this world happens according to Law of Karma. If you open a school in this life, in next life you will be a highly educated person. If you open a hospital in this life, you will get good health in the next life. Similarly, if you kill many people in this life, probably you will have a very bad life in your next birth and so on. Everything is based on Law of Karma.

So, now coming to your question: ***If a husband intentionally deserts his wife by listening to wrong and misleading people, then how will GOD punish him?***

The answer is clear that if the husband knows that what he is doing is wrong but still does it intentionally, then definitely in his next life he will be in misery of some kind for this wrong action he does in this life. There can't be a definite answer but you can guess that in his next life either his family members will not love him or desert him, or nobody will respect him or like him in his next life and he will crave for love and respect from people in his next life. But most important thing to understand is GOD has nothing to do here in his destiny, nor GOD is punishing him here. It's just Law of Karma. Every Action has equal and opposite Reaction. This is true not only for Physics but for the Life Actions as well.

So to learn from this, we should be very cautious about our actions we perform in our life. Even a small hurt or anger or greed or ego you show others can be a reason for your misery in your current life or next life or many coming lives. So love and respect everyone with heart. Be generous towards even those who do bad to you.

Source of this Knowledge: The Hindu scripture "Gita"

Comment: Welcome To Hinduism SE! Pls.Cite sources in your answer.

Comment: Hi, I have added the source in the message. I got this knowledge from GITA. I don't learn shlok's, I understand their real meaning and use them in my life. I hope this make sense.

Comment: I am agree with your answer. God is nothing to do with punishment. It's karma only.